# Arranging Content in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an app that uses Bootstrap 3. There is a grid that consists of two main columns. Content in the left column is left aligned. In the right column, I want the content right-aligned. However, some of the content needs to be vertically aligned against the top. While other content needs to be vertically aligned against the bottom. It will look something like this:

```
 col-sm-9                             col-sm-3
+------------------------------------+------------+
| Content will go                    |     [image]|
| here. The size of this content     |            |
| takes precedence. It could go      |            |
| four lines. Or maybe even six.     |  link here |
+------------------------------------+------------+
```

In an attempt to do this, I have the following:

```
<div class="row" style="display:table">
  <div class="col-sm-9" style="float:none; display:table-cell;">
    Some text goes here
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3" style="float:none; display:table-cell; text-align:right;">
    <div><img alt="My Image" src="..." /></div>
    <div style="vertical-align:bottom;"><a href="#">link here</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, this approach doesn't work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What does it do, exactly? Please provide additional details about your problem, including enough HTML and CSS to completely reproduce your issue. Otherwise, this question risks being closed.

Comment: Is there a reason you gave custom css to `col-sm-9` and `col-sm-3`?

Comment: @TasosK. I would assume it was an attempt to get the vertical alignments to work

Comment: Starter fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/z03wo1kh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the fix to your problem is simply to give the link div absolute positioning and set its position to bottom: 0px; and right: 0px;

```
<div class="row" style="display:table">
  <div class="col-sm-9" id="l-cell">
      Text here
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3" id="r-cell">
    <div><img alt="My Image" src="..." /></div>
    <div id="bottom-left"><a href="#">link here</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

with the css:

```
#l-cell {
    float:none; display:table-cell; background-color:red;
}
#r-cell {
    float:none; display:table-cell; text-align:right; background-color:blue;
}
#bottom-left {
    vertical-align:bottom; position:absolute; bottom:0px; right:0px; background-color:white;
}
```

Example: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8bdr7fto/)